# Вопросы по gitignore

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

Периодически появляются вопросы вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481546/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-gitignore-%D0%B2-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5/481548#481548) по поводу [gitignore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore) по какому-то конкретному проекту. На большинство из них можно ответить дав ссылку на [репозиторий](https://github.com/github/gitignore). Там есть примеры для большинства типов проектов.

Стоит ли отвечать, давая ссылку на конкретный проект (в зависимости от вопроса), или же помечать такие вопросы как дубликаты?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше сделать каноничный ответ с указанием как можно получить готовый файл (указание репозитория на [GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore), ссылка на [сайт](https://www.gitignore.io/)), плюс поясниловка где будет написано что стоит включать а что стоит исключить, если вдруг готового шаблона не найдется. как например в этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474557/179270)

Вновь созданные/создаваемые/существующие вопросы отметить дубликатом.

Comment: Пиар моего вопроса! Конечно же, полностью поддерживаю. =)